# How Facebook, SnapChat, or Gmail iOS apps prevent Fiddler decrypting their https traffic?

Tags: ios, facebook, fiddler

I tried to use Fiddler to capture some iOS apps traffic, ex: Facebook, SnapChat, Gmail, and Instagram.

Instagram is not using https so I can get all the traffic and see the cookies I sent out but Fiddler cannot decrypt other three apps. It only shows something like this:

> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted
>   the parameters below. Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2) Random: 54 3F 49 C4 20 08
>   09 BC A8 84 24 92 08 BF B4 38 39 C9 BB 1C B2 7B 95 6A 39 34 E7 AC FE
>   0F 62 67 SessionID: empty Extensions:     server_name graph.facebook.com
>     elliptic_curves

Could anyone help me understand how they do this so I can use the same technology to protect my app.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title and confusing question. I followed Dave's instruction to install the certificate for iOS and now I can see the facebook traffic. So I use the token from the Fiddler to make some requests and I can see something I should not see, ex: friend list which is only available to that user's friends. But with this token, I can see it. The right question I want to ask is: Do they only use https to protect token? I use FB token to verify my user and give user a token for my service. It's not bank service, just don't want people mess it up. Is https enough?

Comment: OK, based on your comment your new question seems to be wether OAuth provides sufficient protection for your needs. It would be best to submit that as a new question where it can get the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way in which Fiddler can decrypt HTTPS traffic is by using their own certificate. However, when Facebook/Snapchat/Gmail detects that the certificate is not trusted by the system (and in cases will be more strict and limit the certificates within the trusted, so a third party trusted cert might be rejected), it will refuse to connect with the cert.

Fiddler can generate certs for the iOS to accept and install onto the system, but you first need to follow [these instructions](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForiOS):

1. Install [CertMaker](http://www.telerik.com/docs/default-source/fiddler/addons/fiddlercertmaker.exe?sfvrsn=2)
2. Generate the certificate from fiddler, it should then be on your desktop
3. Visit the certificate from your Safari browser (Safari only, others will not work)
4. Install the certificate

From this, you should then be able to sniff traffic from these applications.

So to answer the question again, it's not that they're preventing, it's common for SSL applications to deny responses from the server if the server provides an untrusted certificate. What Fiddler does, is spoof the part of the certificate with its so that when you are communicating over SSL, Fiddler can then use its cert to decrypt your traffic.

To answer the second part of your question, please check out [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397507/sending-device-token-safely-for-apns). Essentially, you can force the user to use a specific certification and thus prevent the user from using installed certs.

However, they can still get around this -- just in a bit more sneaky way, but guided, this is on the client side, anything goes.

Comment: "You can't protect your own app" This is not correct. Some of these applications are performing trust evaluation using SSL pinning, which you can implement in your own application, and is immune to this type of man in the middle attack. Apple has a tech note that details HTTPS trust evaluation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Comment: @quellish I edited my answer to reflect the linked question/SSL pinning. However, the issue still stands, a determined sniffer can still modify the CA certs within the system (when iOS is jailbroken), and thus be able to sniff HTTPS traffic on that iOS device. This is a pretty difficult feat to pull off, but saying that you can protect your app 100% is a lie. You need to still mention that there is a small chance your app's internet traffic will be known. And regardless, if your security relies on the secrecy of the https traffic, then it's security through obscurity.

Comment: If you modify the cert chain, correctly implemented pinning will not be sniffable - the client will not connect to the untrusted host. Modifying the certificate chain isn't terribly difficult. At what point did I say "you can protect your app 100%"? I said your assertion that "you can't protect your own app" was incorrect. You can. You can be strict in your trust evaluation, and not allow your app to connect to untrusted hosts. It's up to you to determine what to trust, *regardless of the trusted roots on the device*. If the remote cert is not the cert you expect, abort. That is SSL pinning.

Comment: And the SO answer you are pointing to is also incorrect :( That is not how SSL pinning works. See the tech note and WWDC 2014 session 704 for an explanation. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#704

Comment: The OP is under the assumption that apps such as these are safe and if he just implements the same thing his will be too. I'm pointing out that there's nothing he can do, and if his application relies on any methods of protection for security it'll be broken.

Comment: The OP says he wants to protect his application in the same way. Nothing in his question indicates he thinks this will reduce his attack surface to 0. Nonetheless, if his application implements pinning correctly, there is no traffic content to sniff.

Comment: I agree, but in this case the OP thinks that applications such Fb/etc are actively protecting themselves. Last time I checked, these applications do not implement SSL pinning. If I were to setup Fiddler and use it properly, I can easily decrypt Snapchat traffic without jailbreaking and changing default CA certs. He is not using Fiddler correctly because he did not [check the decrypt HTTPS checkbox](http://puu.sh/cebHx/9a2b6aadca.png). That is why instead of getting any response, he's getting the cert handshake.

Comment: Again, some of those applications use pinning, which would be an "active protection". The OP is asking how to protect himself from MITM attacks. If you believe this is impossible, say so. If you believe he cannot see the traffic because of his proxy configuration, be explicit - but still offer correct guidance on how to prevent MITM attacks. Your statement "detects that the certificate is not trusted by the system" ignores pinning.

Comment: I provided instructions on how to setup his Fiddler properly because I could tell from the response -- he did not prepare Fiddler and his iOS correctly. Then I proceeded to show methods on how he could protect his app with SSL pinning, and then I finished by saying it's not foolproof. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Yes. "use a specific certification and thus prevent the user from using installed certs." Pinning is checking the certificate provided by the remote host against a whitelisted value known to the client. It does not prevent the user from using the "installed certs". It performs a specific type of trust evaluation against a value known to the application. Pinning, for the purposes of making the content of the transport used by an iOS application immune to interception, CAN be made foolproof - though that is beyond the scope of his question.

Comment: I agreed with everything up the point of "CAN be made foolproof". Are you saying that an application that uses pinning is foolproof? If not, please elaborate. Because at the moment, I can setup my fiddler to sniff Facebook, SnapChat and Gmail, the applications running on my iOS device.

Comment: I said that an iOS application that correctly implements pinning CAN be made foolproof in securing the content of communications over SSL/TLS. What was ambiguous about that?

Comment: I never said it was ambiguous. In earlier comments you stated that "some of *those* applications use pinning", implying that either Facebook, Snapchat or Gmail used pinning. Are you saying that these applications did not correctly implement pinning? Because I can sniff the traffic of these apps no problem -- which is then the opposite of foolproof.

Comment: I can say with a high degree of certainty that recent versions of Facebook did not correctly implement pinning (but at one point, they tried!). I do no have specific knowledge of the other applications listed.

Comment: I'd hate to ask for an example of an application that does implement pinning correctly. But for the moment, I do not see evidence that supports that pinning can be used to prevent the sniffing of https traffic. To a degree yes, but 100% no. However, we really shouldn't be on the topic of 100%, but you did bring up *foolproof*.

Comment: You brought up foolproof, not me. "I do not see evidence that supports that pinning can be used to prevent the sniffing of https traffic". If pinning prevents a connection from being made, there is no content to sniff. Pinning is a well accepted best practice.

Answer (score 11):

Your question revolves around preventing HTTPS man in the middle (MITM) attacks against iOS applications. Using Fiddler or other HTTPS proxies is a form of naive MITM attack that, unfortunately, often works.

HTTP is built on top of a secure transport protocol called TLS (and before that, SSL). The connection is encrypted using public and private keys between trusted parties. And that is where things tend to go wrong. The concept of trust is central to the security of TLS and SSL before it. The server your application connects to provides cryptographic credentials that must be evaluated to establish trust.

Think of this like a passport or driver's license. In most cases, the license checks out. Then you get one with the name McLovin. If you don't actually *look* at the name, date of birth, number, photo, hologram, etc. you may just blindly trust that McLovin is who they say they are. And then you're in trouble.

### Don't trust McLovin.

[image: McLovin]

#### Most applications trust McLovin :(

To protect your application against these kinds of attacks you should implement a more strict set of crendential and trust evaluations. Apple has a tech note, [Technote 2232: HTTPS Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) that details this quite well.

A good start is to implement [SSL Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F). Pinning checks the credential of the remote host against a known value - all or part of that certificate. The iOS application has some copy of that certificate, and when connecting to that host checks the credential the host provides against this "known good" certificate. Some applications just check the meta information, others attempt to checksum the certificate (AFNetworking does this), and others perform a full trust evaluation using the known good certificate against the credential. Apple details this process in the WWDC 2014 session [Building Apps for Enterprise and Education](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#704). If the remote host is not using the expected credentials, the connection is aborted. There is no traffic for an attacker to intercept. If your server's certificate changes often this can be a problem - which is one of several reasons its preferred to check the server's *public key* instead of meta information or a hash. Unfortunately, some server administrators change public keys often. Some think this is more secure. It's not.

Now, obviously this requires the iOS application to have a copy of the "good" certificate, or some part of it. You can include the certificate in your application, or implement your own method of key exchange. Secure key exchange has long been the subject of cryptographic research and is not something to be taken lightly.
Including the certificate in your application is the solution most people use. You may decide it's important to secure this certificate from someone who may have compromised or jailbroken the device. You have a number of different options for doing so. Obviously you could include it as a resource, and encrypt that. You can also include it directly within the application binary, which can be much more difficult for an attacker to access. This can be done by using the `xxd` [tool with Xcode](http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/71839659710/embedding-resource-files-in-a-cocoa-foundation-command), as a script build phase or as a build rule. Obviously, you can implement additional protection on top of that.

If the device has been compromised or the application has been tampered with it's possible the "known good" credential has been altered. This is where the iOS application sandbox can work to your advantage. You can detect many of these scenarios by [implementing receipt validation for your application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW9). Assuming your application is being distributed through an Apple channel such as the iOS App Store, when it's installed it includes a receipt. That can be validated, and that can be used to implement tamper-proofing for many common scenarios.

These are all methods that can be implemented in the client to protect communications over HTTPS from MITM attacks. The server can also expose the client in many more ways, and the server should be regularly audited for vulnerabilies. Use only known strong cryptographic algorithms, stay up to date with current public vulnerabilities, etc.

Of course, if your application is something that can connect to *random* HTTPS services you have no control over, like a web browser, your options are more limited. In those cases, the best you can do when a remote host's credentials are in doubt is give the user the choice to trust or not trust the credentials. On iOS there is no UI for doing so provided by the system frameworks, that would be something your application would have to implement.

This is only one, small facet of securing an iOS application, but your question was specific about man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This will take too much time to implement. I added comment to my post.