# Fiddler doesn't capture all https like in case of snapchat

Tags: https, fiddler, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, snapchat

**Has anyone already found this issue at capturing traffic of snapchat?**

Every https data deriving from other sites via application (of ios, android) are captured successfully by Fiddler but a few apps (appstore, snapchat) don't show anything just that request:

```
CONNECT app.snapchat.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: app.snapchat.com
User-Agent: Snapchat/10.8.1.0 (iPhone8,1; iOS 10.2.1; gzip)
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 59 23 9E E1 1C 23 49 F1 A1 21 6E 60 C5 94 AB E2 9F 09 10 C3 E0 C3 99 9B 78 9B 97 1F 74 69 5F 1C
"Time": 2089.12.12. 15:48:57
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name app.snapchat.com
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18], secp521r1 [0x19]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  sha256_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha384_rsa, sha512_rsa, sha256_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha384_ecdsa, sha512_ecdsa
    NextProtocolNego    empty
    ALPN        http/1.1, http/1.0
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    SignedCertTimestamp (RFC6962)   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
Ciphers: 
    [00FF]  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

What would be done for the unimpeded working?

Extending this issue more what's the reason the fiddler (or other interceptors) isn't able to capture all https data but their Connect handshakes?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is due to certificate pinning. Snapchat is know to use this to prevent MITM attacks.

Take a look at this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543302/1353689

and the links related to it as well.